# How to (py)test a function that relies on the current time?

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

I have a function with the following structure.

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    # ... code
    now = pd.Timestamp('now', tz=0)
    # ... more code
    return result # result depends on "now" variable
```

I cannot take a timestamp right before or after the execution of `foo` and use it for comparisons against the return value, because it will differ from the value of `now` inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a time mocking library, e. g. https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/ to freeze time to a known instant in your test.

```py
def test_foo():
    with freezegun.freeze_time("2021-04-14"):
        result = foo()  # assert that result is correct for the above date
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe include a small example in the answer itself?

Comment: Sure. I was on mobile when answering originally, which makes it tedious to write code. Glad I could help!

Comment: `freezegun` does not seem to influence `pd.Timestamp('now')`. As a workaround, you can use `pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())`.